# Non-existence of approximation algorithm for the knapsack problem

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, approximation

I am working on the following exercise: Prove that if $P \neq NP$, there cannot exist an approximation algorithm $A$ for the knapsack problem (KP) such that $\exists k \in \mathhbb{N}, \forall I \in S: OPT(I) - P_A(I) \leq k$ where $OPT(I)$ is the optimal profit on instance $I$ and $P_A(I)$ is the profit calculated by $A$.

I know that there is a FPTAS $A'$ for the KP which guarantees a solution with profit $P_{A'}(I) \geq (1 - \varepsilon)OPT(I)$ on any instance $I$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.

My approach is to create a contradiction. For this I consider $A = A'$ and aim to show that $P_A(I) \geq (1 - \varepsilon)OPT(I) \geq ... \geq OPT(I) - c$ where $c \in (0,1)$ is a constant. This way, for an adequate choice of $\varepsilon$ I would show that we obtain an optimal solution within polynomial time. However, I struggle how to choose $\varepsilon$.

I need some advice on how to proceed. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The contradiction is a bit more subtle.

Consider an instance `I'` derived from `I` by increasing all the values of the items in `I` `n`-fold. An optimal profit `Opt(I')` is `n`-times the optimal profit of `Opt(I)`, and the solution to both problems is comprised by the same set of items (prove it!).

So, if `A` finds the `Opt(I') - k` solution, it also finds an `Opt(I) - k/n` one. Making `n` large enough, conclude `A` would solve any instance `I` better than `Opt(I) * (1 - eps)` *for any given `eps`*.

For the integer values it is enough to take any `n > k`. For the real values you need some more work, namely to prove that `A'` is not universal, but must depend on `eps`.